# Process killed when pulling variables from another file.sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tmux

I have file.sh which starts a TMUX process:

```
if tmux new -d -c ${INSTALL_DIR} -s ${TMUX_SESSION} bin/${SERVER} --port ${PORT} --galaxy-name ${GALAXY} --max-players ${MAX_PLAYERS}  ${PARAMS} 2> /dev/null
    then
```

Currently all these variables are available at the top of the file:

```
MAX_PLAYERS=20
GALAXY=GalaxyName
#etc
```

Im trying to push some of the variables to another file so that when i push updates to file.sh im not overwriting the clients custom variables
The problem is that the process tmux starts is immediately killed when trying to bring those variables in from file-config.sh

When trying to pull those variables in:

```
source ./file-config.sh
```

Here i was able to call `echo ${GALAXYNAME}` and it worked.
However right after running the `TMUX` command listed above I run this:

if pidof ${SERVER} > /dev/null;

Which always fails, the process is killed right away.
Ive also tried using `cat` and `grep` like so:

```
MAX_PLAYERS=$(grep MAX_PLAYERS= ./file-config.sh | sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/.*=//')
GALAXY=$(grep GALAXY= ./file-config.sh | sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/.*=//')
```

Which give the same result as before. I can echo the variables but the `TMUX` process is killed.

I want to make it clear that the script works 100% as expected if the variables are at the top of file.sh and im not trying to bring them in from another file. Its ONLY when I try to bring variables in from another source does the process kill itself.

EDIT

Thxs to the comment about using bashes debug mode I was able to detect that in both cases the variables had `\r` on the end of them causing them to break the `TMUX` command.

I can remove it by applaying `sed -e 's/\r//g'` to each variable, but Im not sure of the best way to remove `\r` from a sourced variable

```
source filename
variable=$($variable | sed -e 's/\r//g)
```

is there a better option?

Comment: `set -x` is your friend (for purposes of collecting usable debug logs).

Comment: tbh ive never used that, what do you mean by set -x nvm https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-shell-script.html

Comment: BTW, if you want more... *reliable*... advice on writing good bash, I'd suggest [the bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/), and/or the [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). There's a lot of bad advice floating around out there, some of it with surprisingly high Google rankings.

Comment: Here on StackOverflow, every topic has a "tag wiki" -- the one for bash is at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info; not everything it links is perfect, but on the whole, I'd trust that more than random Google results too.